# Does the $form['element']['#disabled'] = TRUE guarantee that the user cannot edit the field or is it just a UI setting

Tags: forms

I have a form element like this:

```
$form['title'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield', 
  '#title' => t('Subject'), 
  '#default_value' => $node->title, 
  '#size' => 60, 
  '#maxlength' => 128, 
  '#disabled' => TRUE,

);
```

Does this make the field 100% non-editable by the user or is it still possible to set a value for this field using manual form submission using jQuery / Postman to the action URL?

Answer (score 4):

If you disable field in backend, the field value won't be actually changed even if you change it in HTML or by JS.
You can test it:
 - disable element in form alter
 - open element in Chrome inspector (or other) and remove `disabled` attribute
 - change value in field and save the form
 - changed value will not be saved